# Задача по С отредактировать файл

Tags: c, файлы

В общем, само задание звучит так: 
*Дан файл, содержащий некоторый текст. Отредактировать файл: после каждой фразы в скобках указать число слов в ней.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000
 
int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("RX-0.txt", "r+");
    char text[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int words = 0;
     
    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("\nFile opened successfully!\n\n");

        while (!feof(file)) {
            fscanf(file, "%c", &text[i]);
            
            if (text[i-1] == ' ' && text[i] != ' ') {
                words++;
            } 

            if (text[i-1] == '.') {
                words++;
                fprintf(file, " %d ", words);
                words = 0; 
            }

            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("\n\nFile closed succesfully!\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Я дошел до такой реализации, однако проблема заключается в том, что если выводить количество слов в консоль, то все нормально, а мне нужен не вывод в консоль, а именно отредактированный файл с количеством слов после фразы. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь

Comment: Заводите новый файл,и в него пишете. Как отладите - добавляете переименование нового в то же имя.

Comment: @MBo, мне по заданию разрешено иметь только один файл и его редактировать

Comment: Значит, считайте всё содержимое в память